# Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found

Tags: python, kubernetes, kubeflow, mlops

I am new to kubectl and kserve.
Tried to implement and create inference service using the below tutorial.
https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/external-add-ons/kserve/first_isvc_kserve/

But while creating the InferenceService I am getting the below error. Can some one help me in this.

```
KServe = KServeClient()
KServe.create(isvc)
Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConfigException                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0b03661604ad> in <module>()
----> 1 KServe = KServeClient()
      2 KServe.create(isvc)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/kubernetes/config/kube_config.py in _get_kube_config_loader(filename, config_dict, persist_config, **kwargs)
    766         if kcfg.config is None:
    767             raise ConfigException(
--> 768                 'Invalid kube-config file. '
    769                 'No configuration found.')
    770         return KubeConfigLoader(

**ConfigException: Invalid kube-config file. No configuration found.**
```

Comment: Is your kube config in the correct place/being referenced correctly

Comment: do you have `~/.kube/config` file? i think `KServeClient` uses `kubernetes`, which then finds the file by default.

Comment: I dont have any config file. https://colab.research.google.com/github/kubeflow/website/blob/master/content/en/docs/external-add-ons/kserve/first_isvc_kserve.ipynb#scrollTo=f8ef0696-7520-4476-96e8-778017f1d075&uniqifier=1 ..